# Google VR View for the Web

Tags: javascript, html, view, virtual-reality

I'm trying to embed some 360 images on my site using Google VR View, but I'm having no luck getting anything to work.  I'm following the Google provided documentation as a guide...

https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web

```
`window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
 function onVrViewLoad() {
  var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
   image: 'img/jtree.jpg',
   is_stereo: false
 });
}`
```

I copied the example code, and am getting errors in the console (see attached screen shots)

Console Errors

[image]

Does anyone know of a tutorial that would better outline how to use this? Or possibly can someone shed some light on what I may be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to open your HTML file in a server.
2. Enable CORS https://enable-cors.org/server.html.
   I find an easy way to enable CORS with the Chrome web server just for your experiment purpose.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had absolutely no luck getting this to work with the instructions provided by Google - guess I'm not versed enough in coding. For me it only worked when I used the iframe, see https://www.museum-joanneum.at/spielwiese/360.

However, the view is still not exactly the same, the info-Tag is not layered over the image in the left lower corner like the demo on Google, but on top of the image and reduces the image height by about 30 pixels. Maybe that's related to the iframe since the instructions state, that the functionality isn't exactly the same as with the JavaScript API.

Also, for my images I had to select "false" for stereo in order to display correctly.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not setting up the directories properly. Is your web server set up so the root is the root of the repo? Are you also getting a 404 error? (looks like vrview.js is not being loaded)

As for places to get help with this, I recommend the vrview-web google group.

Answer (score 0):

you need add this html id on web page.

```
<div id="vrview"></div>
```

Below JavaScript will call out the image on HTML.

```
var vrView;

var scenes = {
    petra: {
        image: 'images/petra.jpg',
        preview: 'images/petra-preview.jpg'
    }
}

function onLoad() {
    vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
        width: '100%',
        height: 480,
        image: 'images/blank.png',
        is_stereo: false,
        is_autopan_off: true
    });

    vrView.on('ready', onVRViewReady);
    vrView.on('modechange', onModeChange);
    vrView.on('getposition', onGetPosition);
    vrView.on('error', onVRViewError);
}


function loadScene(id) {
    console.log('loadScene', id);
    // Set the image
    vrView.setContent({
        image: scenes[id].image,
        preview: scenes[id].preview,
        is_autopan_off: true
    });
}

function onVRViewReady(e) {
    console.log('onVRViewReady');
    loadScene('petra');
}

function onModeChange(e) {
    console.log('onModeChange', e.mode);
}

function onVRViewError(e) {
    console.log('Error! %s', e.message);
}

function onGetPosition(e) {
    console.log(e)
}

window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run those scripts only on the server and then only it will render the texture so you can add your all files in the wamp server path and access through or you can create a web project in asp.net, add your files and build the project. everything will be taken care of by the Visual Studio.
For example

- download [this sample Code](https://github.com/googlevr/vrview)
- Add this in your wamp server path or    create a project in visual
  studio and add these files
- Open your index.html file the in browser